# How to disable Learn More anchor tag in youtube embed iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube

I am using youtube embed iframe for playing videos. If the src of the url does not contain valid URL on playing the video it throws "An error occured. Please try again later'. and there will be Learn More anchor tag. How do I disable that anchor tag using javascript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with JavaScript, as you can not access an iFrame from a different domain.

If you want to be sneaky, you could overlay the iframe with a z-indexed transparent div stop the user clicking in the iframe.